# Are questions about derivations in papers published in scientific journals, on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, soft-question

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but If I have a specific question about a derivation step in a paper published in *Physical Review A*, for example. Can I ask it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably depends on how you word the question itself.

If you simply ask, "How is this step done?" you will likely find the question closed under the homework policy.

If, instead, you ask, "I thought that situation X should apply here, but they say it's Y and I don't see why. Can someone fill in why?" or something similar, the question will likely remain open.

Comment: So basically the moral of the story is that the more details you put into what it is you do and do not understand about the physics, the more likely your question will remain open.

Comment: To put it another way, we will not flesh out an arithmetic computation for you. Such a question *could* be on-topic on Math.SE.